# When setting transaction level in a stored procedure, do the procs that get called stay at the same transaction level?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to be certain that the stored procedures underneath my main calling stored procedure get executed with the same transaction isolation
level.

For example, if I set `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT`, will it stay snapshot if I call another stored procedure within my original stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FirstStoredProc]
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

    EXEC [dbo].[SecondStoredProc]
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SecondStoredProc]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT name
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE type = 'P';
END;

EXEC FirstStoredProc
```

Will the select be run under snapshot isolation?

Comment: Yes. Easily [tested](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=81d3928c397dc54f32abee690527bbf6). Note that if `SecondStoredProc` performs its own `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`, it will be reset to `SNAPSHOT` on exit when we get back to `FirstStoredProc`.

Answer (score 1):

Its in the context of the calling proc. To see this add this line to the proc, SecondStoredProc:

```
dbcc useroptions;
```

and the last line will have an entry for isolation level.

Answer (score 0):

I found it from another stackoverflow question. It does keep its scope.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FirstStoredProc] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT
    SELECT 'PROC 1'
    DBCC USEROPTIONS;
EXEC [dbo].[SecondStoredProc]
END;
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SecondStoredProc] 
AS
BEGIN
--Select name from sys.objects where type = 'P';
SELECT 'PROC 2'
DBCC USEROPTIONS;
END;

DBCC USEROPTIONS;
EXEC FirstStoredProc
```